# Vue.js: Run a method after a delay, but reset the delay if user input happens

Tags: javascript, node.js, vue.js

Suppose I have a form that is retrieving and displaying information from an API based on user input. As the user enters their query (for simplicity, let's say they are changing the number of results per page), the component should react and load the new data. I want to give the user a buffer zone - let's say, 2 seconds. If they enter their input, and 2 seconds passes without any new input, the component will perform an axios request. However, if more input is entered in that time, the 'timeout' will reset back to 2 seconds.

I feel like I would use a watched property to accomplish this but am struggling with the implementation. There's the obvious `setTimeout` method, but that won't allow me to reset the timer - I'd just call it multiple times with a 2 second delay.

How, using Vue.js, can I wait for user input, then wait for 2 seconds of inactivity (on that component), *then* perform an axios request?

Relevant Vue template:

```
<template>
    <input
        type="number"
        v-model.number="perPage" />    
</template>
```

Relevant Vue script:

```
<script>
    export default {
        data: function () {
            return {
                perPage: 25,
            }
        },
        methods: {
            myAxiosCall() {

            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: You might want to look into debouncing. There's a good example in [the docs](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html#Watchers)

Comment: I did find that - but it looks as though it adds a time out _between_ requests, so the first request would run instantly, _then_ a 2 second delay between subsequent requests. Would debouncing allow me to add a delay to the very first one? (I'll admit this is me being a bit of a perfectionist at this point)

Comment: Yes it will, I just didn't read the docs correctly. Awesome!

Comment: I think [Lodash's debounce function](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.10#debounce) won't immediately invoke a function unless you specifically set the `leading` option to true.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As you pointed out you are using setTimeout() method.

**Solution 1**
 -- Do this inside your text watcher

save the result of setTimeout in a variable and use clearTimeout when you need to cancel. like this

```
let x = setTimeout(functionName, time);
//to clear -- when user starts typing clear the previously created timeouts
clearTimeout(x);
```

**Solution 2**

Use debounce (import [lodash](https://lodash.com/docs/#debounce)).
I find first one better. There may be many more approaches.
Accept the answer if it helps.